# SQL: SUM selected Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following MySQL Query:

```
SELECT LieferantID, IsChecked FROM BenutzerZuAbstimmung 
WHERE BenutzerZuAbstimmung.AbstimmungID=9
```

[image: Screenshot of the Result]

[image: Structure of the Table]

I would like to get the three highest rows of `SUM(IsChecked)` but for each `LieferantID`. I have tried different `SELECT` statements but none of them work. I'm quite new to sql... a little explanation would be nice.

Thank you!

Another try: I would like to get the three highest values of `SUM(IsChecked)` by `LieferantID`. For example, if there are 100 Rows in the Table BenutzerZuAbstimmung `where AbstimmungID=9`, then i would like to know which `LieferantID` has the most `IsChecked=1`. It's a m-to-n table.

Comment: You want sum of three latest record with IsChecked=1. Right?
And you want sum of which field's value?

Comment: you need top 3 row sum or 3 rows after sum question id not clear..

Comment: I would like to get the three highest values of SUM(IsChecked) by LieferantID. For example, if there are 100 Rows in the Table BenutzerZuAbstimmung where AbstimmungID=9, then i would like to know which LieferantID has the most IsChecked = 1. It's a m to n table, if you know what i mean. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the whole concept of database and table. What you mention as "database" is only a table. For what you mention, it appears you still need more tables, or to restructure this one

Comment: Database was a spelling mistake. All i know is, that i got a m-to-n table here ("m": Uservotes as IsChecked with their UserID to "n": LieferantIDs). But i cannot figure out how to select this query correctly.

Comment: The topic on the "possible duplicate" does not fit into mine. I do not want to get the highest value of a distinct list.

Comment: Pls re-read the linked topic! You want to get top n records per group. You need to use sum() instead of max().

Comment: I'm sorry, that is the query i was looking for, so the anwer is to use `GROUB BY` in die Query:
    SELECT LieferantID, sum(IsChecked) FROM BenutzerZuAbstimmung GROUP BY LieferantID